# how to specify a variable in nginx path?

Tags: nginx

Is there a way to specify a variable in nginx?
  I'd like to have www.example.com/dm/123

and 123 will be passed to proxy_pass as ?id=123, here is a incomplete nginx config:

```
location /dm {
            proxy_read_timeout 300s;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass   http://localhost:3000/details?id=VARIABLE;
            #  index  index.html index.htm;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex with a named variable:

```
location ~ /dm/(?<var>.+) {
  ... 
  ...
  proxy_pass   http://localhost:3000/details?id=$var;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is positional capture:

```
location ~ /dm/(.+) {
  ... 
  ...
  proxy_pass   http://localhost:3000/details?id=$1;
}
```